# Build android shared lib using ndk-build without have jni folder

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, android-build

I am able to build a android shared library using ndk-build only when all my src are in the jni foler, but, I would like to build a shared library using ndk-build without need jni folder, because my project doesn't have java code, so how could I do that?

my simple Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ctest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I believe you can do it, but you need to place `Android.mk` in `jni/`. There's quite a few similar questions on Stack Overflow. Search for the error you are likely getting (but did not provide): `Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

worked as follows:

```
ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=path/to/path/to/project/Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=path/to/path/to/project
```

Answer (score 3):

I would still recommend using a subdirectory like `jni` for storing the source, to keep the build products in subdirectories such as `obj`, `libs` and `bin` more clearly separated.

But if you have your Android.mk elsewhere, you should be able to do `ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=path/to/Android.mk`. If you don't want to type this every time, you can add a file named `jni/Application.mk` where you type `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=path/to/Android.mk`. Alternatively you have a file named `jni/Android.mk` which then includes the real `Android.mk` from where you store it.

Comment: I tried that, but ndk-build still ask for jni directory.