# Compiling c code using android-ndk and Android.mk

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have installed android-ndk on my 64-bit Unix machine (the steps are in my [previous  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101655/make-standalone-toolchain-sh-always-giving-invalid-ndk-directory) )

Now I can do `$CC hello.c -o hello` and I am getting the executable.

How can I do so using Android.mk.

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := hello
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libutils
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += frameworks/base/include system/core/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Here is the `hello.c` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I call make on this Android.mk file. Is there any way like `mmm /path-to-hello-world/ -B`?

I have searched for examples but all of them include some form of JNI which are not relevant to my case.

Comment: Since you're posting a question I'm going to assume that you're having some kind of problem with your current approach, so please provide more details as to what that problem is.

Comment: @Michael : The problem is that for bigger projects I want to write Android.mk files for various modules, so I need a way to compile using Android.mk

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26024451/1524450  ?

Comment: @Michael : Thanks. It compiled and it worked fine.